# Set Interval only running function once and clear interval is not working (Using react and redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to run a function continuously until a condition is met, but in this test case, until the off button is pressed.  My first issue is that the function does not stop when i press the off button.

```html
let intervalId

function on(){
  intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){     
  setnum(num=>num+1)
  //setnum(num + 1)
  //Line 11 results in the number going up once and if i keep pressing the button it goes up by one but flashes between numbers more and more frantically every press. The off button has no effect.
  //updateUserMoney()
  }, 400);
}

function off(){
  clearInterval(intervalId)
}

return (
<>
  {num}
  <button onClick={()=>on()}>On</button>
  <button onClick={()=>off()}>Off</button>
</>
```

The second issue is that the function I want to run in the interval (that setnum is standing in for) is actually

```html
function updateUserMoney(){
  batch(()=>{
  dispatch(updateUser({money: user.money + 1, energy: user.energy - 1}))
  dispatch(incrementTime(1))        
  })
}
```

Here, the incrementTime function works as intended and continues to increment, but the update user function only fires once.
I think it has the same problem that line 11 has where setnum(num + 1) doesn't work but setnum(num => num + 1) does.  I haven't used the second syntax much and don't understand why it's different can anybody tell me?

Here's the full code

```html
import { useState } from "react";
import { batch, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { incrementTime, updateUser } from "../actions";

const GeneralActions = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const user = useSelector((state)=>state.user)
    const [num, setnum]= useState(0)
  
    let intervalId
    function updateUserMoney(){
        batch(()=>{
            dispatch(updateUser({money: user.money + 1, energy: user.energy - 1}))
            dispatch(incrementTime(1))        
        })
    }
    function on(){
        intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
          updateuserMoney()
          setnum(num=>num+1)
          }, 400);
    }
    function off(){
        clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
    return (
    <>
    <br/>
        <>{num}</>
        <button onClick={()=>on()}>On</button>
        <button onClick={()=>off()}>Off</button>
    </>
    );
}
 
export default GeneralActions;
```

Any insight is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How are you calling `updateUserMoney`? Every time you component re-rennders, your entire function body is executed, redefining variables such as `let intervalId`. If you want persistant variables accross renders, use a ref: `useRef()`

Comment: Im replacing setnum with updateUserMoney in the on function.  That makes sense and i got the interval working with useState().  I'll look into replacing it with useRef() cause that seems more fitting.  But I still have the issue of setnum(num + 1) and updateUserMoney() only incrementing the number once.  What is the difference between setnum(num=>num+ 1) and setnum(num + 1)?

Comment: Yeah, `useRef()` would be more fitting, the state is more appropriate when you use the value in your JSX that you render, which `intervalId` isn't being used for.  `num=>num+ 1` will grab the latest value of your `num` state and add 1 to it, whereas `num+1` will grab the value of `num` from the surrounding scope add 1 to it, which isn't necessarily going to be the most up-to-date value of `num`.

Comment: I'm still unclear about  `updateUserMoney()` gets called, but if you're calling it in the `setInterval()` then your issue is to do with closures. While your app runs, you' create many "versions" of the `updateUserMoney` function. Each re-renders, your function body executes, creating a new `updateUserMoney`. The value of `num` inside of `updateUserMoney` will refer to the `num` state at the time that version of the `updateUserMoney` was defined. So when `on()` gets called, your interval will execute a version of `updateUserMoney` that potentially refers to an old value of `num`

Comment: If you can [edit] your question to clarify how your `updateUserMoney()` is being called then I can add a full answer with more details for `useRef()` and the `num` closure issue.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I updated it.  Yes i want to call updateUserMoney() in the interval

Comment: i think i mostly understand the issue  conceptually but I can't figure out a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you set a new state value in React, your component will rerender. When your `GeneralActions` component rerenders, your entire function runs again:

```js
const GeneralActions = () => {
  // code in here runs each render 
}
```

This means things such as `intervalId`, will be set to `undefined` when it runs `let intervalId;` again, and so on this particular render you lose the reference for whatever you may have set it to in the previous render. As a result, when you call `off()`, it won't be able to refer to the `intervalId` that you set in your previous render, and so the interval won't be cleared. If you want persistent variables (that aren't related to state), you can use the [`useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook like so:

```js
const GeneralActions = () => {
  const intervalIdRef = useRef();
  ...
  
  function on(){
    clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current); // clear any currently running intervals
    intervalIdRef.current = setInterval(function(){
      ...
    }, 400);
  }

  function off(){
    clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current);
  }
}
```

One thing that I've added above is to clear any already created intervals when `on()` is executed, that way you won't queue multiple. You should also call `off()` when your component unmounts so that you don't try and update your state when the component no longer exists. This can be done using `useEffect()` with an empty dependency array:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  return () => off();
}, []);
```

That should sort out the issue relating to being unable to clear your timer.

Your other issue is with regards to `setNum()` is that you have a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over the `num` variable for the `setTimeout()` callback. As mentioned above, every time your component re-renders, your function body is executed, so all of the variables/functions are declared again, in essence creating different "versions" of the `num` state each render. The problem you're facing is that when you call `setInterval(function(){})`, the `num` variable within `function() {}` will refer to the `num` version at the time the function was created/when `setInterval()` function was called. This means that as you update the `num` state, your component re-renders, and creates a new `num` version with the updated value, but the function that you've passed to `setInterval()` still refers to the old `num`. So `setNum(num + 1)` will always add `1` to the old number value. However, when you use `useState(num => num + 1)`, the `num` variable that you're referring to isn't the `num` "version"/variable from the surrounding scope of the function you defined, but rather, it is the most up to date version of the `num` state, which allows you to update `num` correctly.

Comment: Thank you Nick!  I now have it working using useRef() and changed my updateUser action to work like my increment time function.

Comment: I want to stop the interval when user.energy == 0 but now I'm having trouble with that.  How would i go about stopping the interval when a condition is met without a button press?  I can see that the problem is the same but am not sure about a solution yet.

Comment: I got it working using `    useEffect(() => {
        if(user.currentEnergy<2){

            return () => clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current);
        }
      }, [user.currentEnergy]);` .  But I feel there's a better way to do it.

Comment: @Penn That's fairly decent for your current setup. I would however recommend looking a Dan Abramov post about creating a `useInterval()` hook (see [here](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)). It's a really nice guide and there is a part within it that shows you how you can pause your interval/turn it off.  The advantage of using this hook is that it stops the closure issue that you're facing, as it redefines the callback that gets called by the `setInterval()` call for each new "version"/rerender